# How to simulate Jumping in Pygame for this particular code

Tags: python, pygame, pycharm, 2d-games

I have been trying to simulate the jump in the Pygame code but haven't been able to successfully implement it. There is a rectangle of dimension 10 by 10 and I want that rectangle to jump when <kbd>SPACE</kbd> is press. I am keeping this code independent of gravity for now.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
ScreenLenX = 1000
ScreenLenY = 500
win = pygame.display.set_mode((ScreenLenX, ScreenLenY))
pygame.display.set_caption("aman")
run = True
Xcord = 100
Ycord = 100
length = 10
height = 10
vel = 2
xmove = 1
ymove = 1
while run:
  #pygame.time.delay(1)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        print(event)
        if event.type ==pygame.QUIT:

            run = False

    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and Xcord <= ScreenLenX-length:
        Xcord += vel
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and Xcord >= 0:
        Xcord -= vel

     if keys[pygame.K_UP] and Ycord >= 0:
            Ycord -= vel
     if keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and Ycord <= ScreenLenY - height:
            Ycord += vel
     win.fill((0, 0, 0))
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0), (Xcord, Ycord, length, height))
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()


    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [How to make a character jump in Pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70591591/how-to-make-a-character-jump-in-pygame). Add a variable `jump` and initialize it by 0, before the main loop:

```py
jump = 0  
while run:
    # [...]
```

Only react on `pygame.K_SPACE`, if player is allowed to jump and stays on the ground. If this is fulfilled then set `jump` to the desired "jump" height:

```py
if keys[pygame.K_SPACE] and Ycord == ScreenLenY - height:
    jump = 300
```

As long as `jump` is greater than 0, move the player upwards and decease `jump` by the same amount, in the main loop.
If the player is not jumping that let him fall dawn, till he reaches the ground:

```py
 if jump > 0:
    Ycord -= vel
    jump -= vel
elif Ycord < ScreenLenY - height:
    Ycord += 1
```

See the demo, where I applied the suggestions to your code:

[image]

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()

ScreenLenX, ScreenLenY = (1000, 500)
win = pygame.display.set_mode((ScreenLenX, ScreenLenY))
pygame.display.set_caption("aman")
Xcord, Ycord = (100, 100)
length, height = (10, 10)
xmove, ymove = (1, 1)
vel = 2
jump = 0

run = True
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while run:
    #clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        print(event)
        if event.type ==pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and Xcord <= ScreenLenX-length:
        Xcord += vel
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and Xcord >= 0:
        Xcord -= vel

    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE] and Ycord == ScreenLenY - height:
        jump = 300

    if jump > 0:
        Ycord -= vel
        jump -= vel
    elif Ycord < ScreenLenY - height:
        Ycord += 1

    win.fill((0, 0, 0))
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0), (Xcord, Ycord, length, height))

    pygame.display.update()
```