# Making Fluid Jump Motion in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I coded a jumping motion for my character, however, instead of one proper fluid motion the changes come every time I press the Up Arrow Key. I have tried making the code using a while loop, but the screen freezes then. I tried making the code an event and then calling it, no luck. I even got desperate and tried watching a YouTube video and looking at the question solved right here on Stack Overflow but I couldn't solve my problem. Here is the code:

```
#Variables
player_img = pygame.image.load('car.png')
player_x = 40
player_y = 390

vel = 5

isJump = False
jumpCount = 10
player_pass_range = range(10,21)

class Player():
    def draw_player():
        screen.blit(player_img, (player_x, player_y))

#Main Loop
while playing:
    screen.fill((0, 0, 255))         

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running, playing, credits_menu, options_menu = False, False, False, False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                if jumpCount >= -10:
                    player_y -= (jumpCount * abs(jumpCount)) * 0.5
                    jumpCount -= 1
                else: # This will execute if our jump is finished
                   jumpCount = 10
                   isJump = False

    #Draw Objects
    Player.draw_player()

    #Update Screen
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a character jump in Pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70591591/how-to-make-a-character-jump-in-pygame)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [How to make a character jump in Pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70591591/how-to-make-a-character-jump-in-pygame/70591592#70591592)

The jump animation must be done in the application loop instead of the event loop. Set `isJump` to `True` when the key is pressed. Animate the player in the application loop depending on `isJump`:

```py
while playing:
    screen.fill((0, 0, 255))         

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running, playing, credits_menu, options_menu = False, False, False, False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                isJump = True

    if isJump:
        if jumpCount >= -10:
            player_y -= (jumpCount * abs(jumpCount)) * 0.5
            jumpCount -= 1
        else: # This will execute if our jump is finished
            jumpCount = 10
            isJump = False

    # [...]
```