# Throttle keypresses in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I was recently coding a platformer game, when I faced into a problem: The user could spam space to jump infinitely.

Here is my code:

```
def __init__(self, pos):
    super().__init__()
    self.image = pygame.Surface((32, 64))
    self.image.fill("green")
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = pos)
    self.direction = pygame.math.Vector2(0, 0)
    self.speed = speed
    self.gravity = gravity
    self.jump_height = jump_height

def get_input(self):
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]: pass
    elif keys[pygame.K_LEFT]: self.direction.x = -1
    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]: self.direction.x = 1
    else: self.direction.x = 0
    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        self.jump()
```

I tried several things, such as implementing a `self.antispam` boolean, set to `True`, at the `__init__` method that turns into `False` when the space key is pressed, and then turns `True` again after the jump method, or turning the `jump` method into a coroutine to make an asyncio loop, but none of them worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To jump you have to use `KEYDOWN` instead of `pygame.key.get_pressed()`. Use `pygame.key.get_pressed()` to move but not to jump.
[`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) returns a sequence with the state of each key. If a key is held down, the state for the key is `True`, otherwise `False`. Use [`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) to evaluate the current state of a button and get continuous movement.
The keyboard events (see [pygame.event](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) module) occur only once when the state of a key changes. The `KEYDOWN` event occurs once every time a key is pressed. `KEYUP` occurs once every time a key is released. Use the keyboard events for a single action like jumping or spawning a bullet.

Make sure you only call `pygame.get.event()` once (see [Faster version of 'pygame.event.get()'. Why are events being missed and why are the events delayed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58086113/faster-version-of-pygame-event-get-why-are-events-being-missed-and-why-are/58087070#58087070)):

```py
    def get_input(self, event_list):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]: pass
        elif keys[pygame.K_LEFT]: self.direction.x = -1
        elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]: self.direction.x = 1
        else: self.direction.x = 0

        for event in event_list:
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDONW and event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                self.jump()
```

```py
# application loop
while run:
    # event loop
    event_list = pygame.get.event()
    for event in event_list:
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            # [...]

    player.get_input(event_list)
```

---

The other option is to state if <kbd>SPACE</kbd> was pressed in previous frames. So you can detect that the <kbd>SPACE</kbd> is hold down:

```
def __init__(self, pos):
    super().__init__()
    # [...]
   
    self.space_was_pressed = False

def get_input(self):
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    # [...]         

    space_is_pressed = keys[pygame.K_SPACE]  
    if space_is_pressed and not self.space_was_pressed:
        self.jump()
    self.space_was_pressed = space_is_pressed
```

---

See also [How to make a character jump in Pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70591591/how-to-make-a-character-jump-in-pygame/70591592#70591592)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I'll make sure to check it out !