# when character jumps it doesn't come back to the ground

Tags: python, pygame

First off, yes I'm a noob but I have ready meany tutorials on getting a character to jump which doesn't seem too complicated but it's not working. The character keeps incrementing up the screen.

It seems the biggest challenge is using a usb controller but I don't want to use a keyboard to controll the character's movement.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated. Just to get this far it took me a week...

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

size = (800,600)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
x = 50
y = 550
width = 50
height = 50
speed = 5
joystick = None
vel = 5
isJump = False
jumpCount = 0


done = False
while not done:
    clock.tick(100)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==pygame.K_RETURN:
                done = True

    if joystick:
        axis_x, axis_y = (joystick.get_axis(0), joystick.get_axis(4))
        if abs(axis_x) > 0.1:
            x += speed * axis_x
        #if abs(axis_y) > 0.1:
         #   pos[1] += speed * axis_y
           
        buttons = joystick.get_numbuttons()
        for i in range( buttons ):
            button = joystick.get_button( i )
            if button == 1:
                isJump = True
                jumpCount = 10

                if isJump:
                    if jumpCount > 0:
                        y -= 5
                elif jumpCount <= 0:
                        y += 5
                        jumpCount -= 1
                if jumpCount == -10:
                        isJump = False

    else:
        if pygame.joystick.get_count() > 0:
            joystick = pygame.joystick.Joystick(0)
            joystick.init()
            print("joystick initialized")

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,255,255), (x, y, width, height))
    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.display.update() 


pygame.quit()
```

[image]

Comment: Anyway, your problem has nothing to do with the USB controller. Pressing the button triggers the jump. It only sets `isJump`. But as soon as the jump is started, it must be calculated in the application loop. (not in the button evaluation loop)

Comment: I'm not sure how I can use my usb controller with your code? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with the USB controller. Pressing the button triggers the jump. It only sets `isJump`. But as soon as the jump is started, it must be calculated in the application loop. Also see [How to make a character jump in Pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70591591/how-to-make-a-character-jump-in-pygame/70591592#70591592):

```py
isJump = False
jumpCount = 0

done = False
while not done:
    clock.tick(100)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==pygame.K_RETURN:
                done = True

    if joystick:
        axis_x, axis_y = (joystick.get_axis(0), joystick.get_axis(4))
        if abs(axis_x) > 0.1:
            x += speed * axis_x
           
        buttons = joystick.get_numbuttons()
        for i in range( buttons ):
            button = joystick.get_button( i )
            if button == 1 and not isJump:               # <---
                isJump = True
                jumpCount = 10

    else:
        if pygame.joystick.get_count() > 0:
            joystick = pygame.joystick.Joystick(0)
            joystick.init()
            print("joystick initialized")


    if isJump:                                           # <---
        if jumpCount > 0:
            y -= 5
        elif jumpCount <= 0:
            y += 5
        jumpCount -= 1
        if jumpCount == -10:
            isJump = False

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,255,255), (x, y, width, height))
    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.display.update() 


pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Hey Rabbid76, when I change the numbers to make the character jump higher the character climbs up the screen again

Comment: Which numbers? Either you have to change `y -= 5` and `y += 5`. Or you have to change the `jumpCount`, but you have to change `10` and `-10` (`jumpCount = 10` and `if jumpCount == -10:`)